# setTimeout() in await axios get request

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want my await axios.get() to be delayed. How can I incorporate a setTimeout in my function?

```
export function functionName() {

  return useMutation(
    async filter => {
      const {data} = await axios.post<Core.Paths.CreateResponse.RequestBody, AxiosResponse<string>>(
        "/path/api/response", filter
      );
      const {data: blob} = await axios.get(`/path/api/document/${data}`, {responseType: "blob"});
      return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    },
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Is your `get` being called before you have a result from the `post`? Is that why you want a "delay"?

Comment: @Igor No I need a delay to do some testing.

Comment: Testing locally or unit testing? Local testing you can just add a break point. Unit testing you should be testing in such a way that you specify when an outstanding promise (or promises) are resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce a delay via Promise.

```js
const delay = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
};

const mutation = async (name) => {
  console.log(`Ran: ${name}`);
};

const someFuction = async () => {
  await mutation('mutation one');

  await delay();

  await mutation('mutation two');
};

someFuction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you surround your code with setTimeout then:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       setTimeout(() => {
              const {data: blob} = await axios.get(`/path/api/document/${data}`, {responseType: "blob"});
              resolve(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        }, {yourDelayHere});
   });
```

Comment: agree, with Promise should be better